# jQuery UI autocomplete with ashx

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, jquery-ui

Currently trying to implement an autocomplete on a clients website which searches through products and textpages. For this, I've made a generic handler that returns anonymous objects as JSON. My anonymous object looks like this:

```
new
{
    Name = product.Name,
    Url = product.Url,
    ImageUrl = imageUrl
});
```

The list of objects gets serialized with a standard .NET JavascriptSerializer.

And my javascript looks like this:

```
searchField.autocomplete({
    source: "/handlers/SearchHandler.ashx",        
    response: function (event, ui) {
        ...
    }
});
```

I'm a bit stuck when it comes to getting the values from JSON into the autocomplete dropdownbox though. Also, I want to use the results as links, so when the user clicks on a result in the dropdown, he/she gets redirected to the page/product.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

**Solution:**

```
searchField.autocomplete({
    source: "/handlers/SearchHandler.ashx?nodeId=" + currentNodeId,
    search: function (event, ui) {
        searchField.css("background-image", "url('../img/ajax-loader-small.gif')");
    },
    response: function (event, ui) {                        
        searchField.css("background-image", "");
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {    
        return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a href='" + item.Url + "'>" + item.Name + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Comment: You can loop through the resultset and make a list of a tags inside a div that is placed underneath the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the sample for a *static* source for a *dynamic* purpose.

Your source-property should not be a `url`, but a `function`:

```
.autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "/handlers/SearchHandler.ashx", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, response );
    }, ...
}) 
.data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, product ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
        .append( "<a href=" + product.Url + ">" + product.Name + "</a>" )
        .appendTo( ul );
};
```

The correct samples are found [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) (source) and [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) (custom display).

**Based on the comments, only alter your rendering to handle your products-response (see the second link).**

Comment: I don't think he has to go to the extent of a custom source function, this example clearly shows source being set as a URL: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: You are right, my bad. I looked at the multiple remote sample. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi :-) Thanks a lot for your input. I got it to show the results by specifying my "Name" field as "label" and my "Url" field as "value". Now I just need to make the results clickable links to the "value" which is the url...

Comment: That's the .data(...) part from my answer. This enables you to add your own html.

Comment: Alright, for the new version of jQuery UI, it seems to be the "ui-autocomplete"  and "ui-autocomplete-item" classes that should be used, though :-) Also, specifying the ashx url as a string works aswell ;-)

Comment: Ah, versioning differences... Nice you found that yourself. I hope my answer still was a little helpful.

Comment: Absolutely :-) thanks a lot for your help, Jacco! Appreciated!